# This is a matter of numerical sequences, it involves Arithmetic Progression.

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Considering that the numerical sequence $a_n, n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ shown in table I is constructed by intercalating the terms of the three sequences presented in table II, judge the following items.

The terms $3n - 1, n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ of the sequence $a_n$ form a geometric progression of ratio 2.

Is it correct to say that $a_{28} < a_{291}$?

[image]

Comment: Could you explain me what does this statement means? 
The terms 3n - 1, n = 1, 2, 3, ... of the sequence an form a geometric progression of ratio 2.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @CrystalWolftron I believe it refers to the sequence $a_{3n-1},\ n=1,2,\dots$

Comment: Neither $28$ nor $291$ are of the for $3n-1$ so neither of them are in the exponential sequence which outstrip the other sequences very fast.  $28$ is of the form $3n+1$ is it is geometric sequence which increases fasert than the arithmetic sequence, which is what terms of the form $3n$ are (which $291$ is) so $a_{28=3*9+1}=(9+1)^2=100$ does surpass $a_{291=3*97}= 97$.  But $a_{25}= 81$ *is* less than $a_{288}=96$. However $3*7-1=20$ puts $a_{20}$ in the exponentail sequence $a_{20}=2^7=128$ outstrips the other two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $28 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so $a_{28}$ is in the first sequence and $28=3*9 + 1$ so it is the $9+1=10$ term so $a_{28}=10^2=100$.

And $291\equiv 3\pmod 3$ so $a_{291}$ is in the third sequence.  And $291 = 3*96 + 3$ so it is the $96+1=97$th term.  So  $a_{291}  = 97$.

So, no, $a_{28} > a_{291}$.

Note if $b_k = k^2$ and $c_k = 2^k$ and $d_k = k$ then

$a_{3m + n; n=1,2,3}=\begin{cases}b_{m+1}&n=1\\c_{m+1}&n=2;\\d_{m+1}&n=3\end{cases}$